# Saving and retrieving Blob data from MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to do something as simple as saving files in a mongodb collection using the django_mongodb_engine, but I am having a lot of difficulty.

So far I've only been able to get it to work by converting the file to base64 before saving it in the database, and then decoding it from base64 when retrieving it. I don't want to do it this way since converting to base64 back and forth might occupy more resources than this operation should actually take up, although I could be wrong.

So can someone show me the correct way of saving and retrieving binary data from the MongoDB with the django_mongodb_engine?

Code so far:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import *

class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip_file = BlobField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from my_project.models import *

def index(request):
    f = open('myfile.zip')
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()

    record = TestModel.objects.create(
        name = "My File",
        zip_file = contents
    )

    result = TestModel.objects.filter(name = "My File")

    zip_contents = result[0].zip_file

    response = HttpResponse(zip_contents, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="My_File.zip"'
    return response
```

Oh and please don't tell me to use GridFS since the files I will be storing will be way under 16MB and will be somewhere around 2.5MB - 3.5MB at most.

Comment: django_mongodb_engine does not seem to implement any of it's own methods for handling binary data, which otherwise MongoDB does quite well. Instead it is relying on the django implementation for BlobField(). Would you be open switching ORM/ODM? Mongoengine for instance, supports a [BinaryField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.BinaryField) implementation where the driver saves and returns this correctly.

Comment: @NeilLunn, guess I have no choice. After messing around with it some more, I've ran into a lot of other problems using the django_mongodb_engine, so it doesn't look like they have good support for it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NeilLunn pointed out, django_mongodb_engine doesn't have support for binary data fields, and it's better to altogether use mongoengine's ORM.

My working code:

models.py

```
from mongoengine import *

class TestModel(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=50)
    zip_file = BinaryField()
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from my_project.models import *

def index(request):
    f = open('myfile.zip')
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()

    record = TestModel(name = 'My File', zip_file = contents)
    record.save()

    result = SkinDetails.objects(name='Metro Skin')

    zip_contents = result[0].zip_file

    response = HttpResponse(zip_contents, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="My_File.zip"'
    return response
```